# How to do an XML Serialization with force creating all obligatory elements

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd, xmlserializer

i have generated a cs-classes with the xsd-tool from some xml scheme.
The scheme is a very complex scheme generated from uml-class descriptions.
Now I have written a simple test to ensure the functionality of the generated xsd-classes.
The test uses `XmlSerializer` to create the xml-file.

In my XSD-scheme there are some obligatory elements (definition with `minocc=1` and `maxocc=1` by xsd-default).

For example (simplified):

```
<xs:element name="order">
    <xs:complexType>
       ...
         <xs:element name="orderId" type="string"/>
         <xs:element name="material" type="Material"/>
       ...
    <xs:complexType>
```

Material is a complex type, which consists of several elements. It is part of order.

These elements should always exists in the resulting xml-file, even if they are empty or contains only empty elements. Now, if I serialize a class instance to an xml-file, only the elements appear where the class-propertys contain a value. If I set orderId the orderId-element appears, but not the material-element because in my class instance it's null. As a result my xml-file is not valid to the xsd-schema.

Do you have an idea how i can validate the resulting xml-file with my xsd file during serialization?  Is there a way to tell `XmlSerializer` that it should always generate obligatory elements (perhaps with a default value)?
Or is there a way to validate the structure of the class instance that should be serialized?

Comment: You could always supply a non-`null` value?

Comment: the problem I have is, that the xsd-schema and the resulting class structure is very complex and I don't want to set all propertys not needed.

Comment: but surely the xsd is telling you they *are* needed...

Comment: yes, thats right, but even if i had created the c# classes from my xsd file, the serialization isn't conform to it

Comment: xsd or not, it can't invent data. XmlSerializer is largely a direct map to objects - if you want an element, it must have an object to look at.

Comment: ok, thats quite true, but is there a way to check if the structure of the class instance fulfils the validation-rules against a xsd-scheme?

Comment: IIRC both XmlReader and XmlWriter support validation against xsd

Comment: I've found that XmlWriter by itself can't validate, but there is an XmlSchemaValidator which could validate.

Comment: `XmlWriter` certainly _can_ validate. Use `XmlWriter.Create()` with an `XmlWriterSettings` that specifies validation. But, like Marc says, the XmlSerializer serializes what you give it to serialize. If you give it an object that will produce a document that's invalid according to the schema, then that's what it will produce, on the assumption that, if you didn't want that output, you would have provided better input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot generate automatically elements to fulfill your required rules.
On your second question you can validate the generated xml with XmlReader and XmlSchema objects.
A small example would look like this:

```
        public IList<string> Validate(TextReader reader, XmlSchema schema)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.Schemas.Add(schema);
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

            List<string> errors = new List<string>();

            settings.ValidationEventHandler += (sender, e) =>
            {
                errors.Add(string.Format("Line {0} at position {1}{2}{3}",
                        e.Exception.LineNumber, e.Exception.LinePosition,
                                    Environment.NewLine, e.Message));
            };


            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(reader, settings);
            while (xmlReader.Read()) { };

            return errors;
        }
```

This example takes a TextReader (can be a StreamReader, StringReader etc. ) and an XmlSchema object (you can construct one from the xsd file or whatever - check the documentation for it) and returns a list of validation errors.